# How to Convert PNG Transparent Background to JPG White Background?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm converting a PNG to JPG. The transparent background turns black by default. I need it to be white.

What is the FFmpeg command to set the alpha channel to a color?

I think it has something to do with the alphamerge and alphaextract Filters.

```
ffmpeg -i image.png -qscale:v 2 image.jpg
```

This replaces white with transparency when converting to png:

```
-vf chromakey=white
```

Comment: Why do you use ffmpeg for this task? As an obvious alternative, with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)
you could simply do `convert image.png -background white -flatten image.jpg`.

Comment: @Meyer It's part of a project I'm working on that requires ffmpeg. If it is not possible to do with ffmpeg alone, I will leave it as is, default black.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the geq filter.

```
ffmpeg -i in.png -vf format=yuva444p,geq='if(lte(alpha(X,Y),16),255,p(X,Y))':'if(lte(alpha(X,Y),16),128,p(X,Y))':'if(lte(alpha(X,Y),16),128,p(X,Y))' out.jpg
```

If your alpha is a pure black and white image, change `16` to `1`.