# ffmpeg gif with color instead transparency

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

I create a gif with transparency by:

```
ffmpeg -y -i _frame%d.png -vf palettegen=reserve_transparent=1 palette.png
ffmpeg -framerate 8 -i _frame%d.png -i palette.png -lavfi paletteuse=alpha_threshold=128 -gifflags -offsetting animation.gif
```

I need also to create another gif from it with a specific color instead of the transparency. What would be a fast way to do that?

Comment: Once method is to use the geq filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346323/how-to-convert-png-transparent-background-to-jpg-white-background

Comment: thanks, this helped me. I can't accept it as an answer as comment